# Trying to make similar kivy calculator with user input

Tags: kivy

I'm just a begginer, and i try to make some calculator with user input on kivy.
And i cant find why my code have issue TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Label' and 'int'
Can someone pleas help me with some adwises?

```
class calculate(GridLayout):
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(calculate, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.cols = 2
    self.rows = 5

    self.label1 = Label(text='Width in mm : ')
    self.add_widget(self.label1)

    self.user_data1 = TextInput(multiline=False)
    self.add_widget(self.user_data1)

    self.label2 = Label(text='Height in mm : ')
    self.add_widget(self.label2)

    self.user_data2 = TextInput(multiline=False)
    self.add_widget(self.user_data2)

    self.label3 = Label(text='Mass in gr : ')
    self.add_widget(self.label3)

    self.user_data3 = TextInput(multiline=False)
    self.add_widget(self.user_data3)

    self.label4 = Label(text='Mass in kg : ')
    self.add_widget(self.label4)

    self.user_data4 = TextInput(multiline=False)
    self.add_widget(self.user_data4)

    self.button = Button(text='Calculate')
    self.button.bind(on_press=self.on_user_press)
    self.add_widget(self.button)

    self.calculate = Label(text='Sheets : ')
    self.add_widget(self.calculate)

def on_user_press(self, event):
    self.calculate.number = NumericProperty(self.label4 / (self.label3 / 1000) / (self.label2 / 1000) / (self.label1 / 1000))


class Calculator(App):
    def build(self):
        return calculate()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Calculator().run()
```

Comment: Your `NumericProperty` is trying to do arithmetic with `Label` objects. That cannot work, you can only do arithmetic with numbers.

Comment: thx a lot. Didn't see that i use labels. But it's still doesn't work when i change it with user input.

Comment: What error do you get now?